# Magento cart shows short description twice

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

In the magento cart the short description is shown twice.
[image]

The code in /app/design/frontend/my_template/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
is

```
<?php if ($_options = $this->getOptionList()):?>
        <dl class="item-options">
            <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
            <?php $_formatedOptionValue = $this->getFormatedOptionValue($_option) ?>
            <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
            <dd<?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?> class="truncated"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['value'] ?>
                <?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?>
                <div class="truncated_full_value">
                    <dl class="item-options">
                        <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
                        <dd><?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['full_view'] ?></dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
        <?php endif;?>
```

Where is the template file, in which I can edit the short description

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you translated "Short description" and "Description" both to "Bescheibung" (funny typo btw).

The description is usually *not* displayed in the cart, so it depends on your custom theme.

Or if you use `Firegento_GermanSetup` (or `Firegento_MageSetup`), you have configured both attributes to be shown in the cart. In the admin panel go to `Catalog > Manage Attributes` and change this configuration either for `description` or for `short_description`